# How to get a BlockMatrix of n entries initialized to 1.0/n in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

My code looks like:

```
double[] ones=new double[n];
Arrays.fill(ones, 1.0/n);
Matrix m_ones = Matrices.dense(ones.length,1,ones);
```

I want to get a BlockMatrix out of m_ones or a better way to do it.
I tried:

```
JavaRDD<Matrix> Blocks=jsc.parallelize(m_ones);
BlockMatrix bm=new BlockMatrix(Blocks);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static BlockMatrix initBM(JavaSparkContext jsc,long nr,double val){
    List<MatrixEntry> mle=new ArrayList<MatrixEntry>();
    for(int i=0; i<nr; i++)
        mle.add(new MatrixEntry((long)i,(long) 0,val));

    JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> meRDD = jsc.parallelize(mle);
    CoordinateMatrix tmp= new CoordinateMatrix(meRDD.rdd());
    BlockMatrix bm=tmp.toBlockMatrix();

   return(bm);
}
```